# SFTP message actual length is different than header length

Tags: c#, ssh, sftp

I have an SFTP server written in C#.

There is the SSH layer and then the "ssh data" field which is contains the SFTP message.

When I move the message (SSH data) to the SFTP layer, there are the basic headers.

1. Message Length
2. Message Type
3. Request ID

In some of the messages I get, the actual length is different than the length in the header(expected length).

When it happens, most of the time the actual length is smaller than the expected length.

What should I do when it happens?

1. Aggregate the message with the next packet
2. Disconnect the client
3. Other option

And also what to do in case the actual length is bigger than the expected length.

Code example of SFTP layer:

```
public void OnInput(byte[] data)
{
    DataWorker reader = new DataWorker(data);             

    if (reader.DataAvailable >= 5)
    {
        try
        {
            var msglength = reader.ReadUInt32();
 
            if (reader.DataAvailable != msglength)
            {
                //DoSome
            }

            var msgtype = (SftpMessageType)(int)reader.ReadByte();

            switch (msgtype)
            {
                case SftpMessageType.SSH_FXP_INIT:
                    _logger.Log(LogLevel.Information, "FXP_INIT");
                    HandleInit(reader);
                    break;

                //etc..
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _channel?.SendClose(1);
            return;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        _logger.Log(LogLevel.Error, $"no data avialble. data length is: {reader.DataAvailable}.");
    }
}
```

I tried to aggregate the messages, it works most of the time.

But I don't know if this the correct solution, and also I don't know what to do in case the actual length is bigger the expected length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is "the actual length"? There is no such thing. This (and any) protocol defines what length is, that is the most important thing. The only other length that you encounter is the length of currently loaded packet.

Typically an application protocol is implemented over some transport protocol. In this case we consider a reliable, stream protocol, i.e. the TCP or TLS. This kind of transport protocol has "read" and "write" operations.

So how communication between client and server works? A client constructs a message X and calls "write" on that message. But how would the server read it? The naive approach is to simply call "read" and process it. But that's wrong, because there are actually three possibilities:

1. The "read" operation returned exactly the message send by the client.
2. The "read" operation returned only a piece of previously send message. This may and does happen, because fragmentation can happen at any hop between the client and server.
3. The "read" operation returned more than one message. And not necessarily 2 messages, say 1.3 is possible as well. And so is 5 messages. This may and does happen, especially when multiple messages are send quickly in succession. The underlying TCP stack may concatenate multiple small packets into one big, see e.g. [Nagle's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm).

And therefore when you write stream code you need to handle all of those above. As it is, your code does not do this. You only implemented point 1, and that's why you see those inconsistencies.

> What should I do when it happens?

Properly handle it. Its a bit difficult to give you concrete example of the code, because I don't even know what framework you use. Either way a general algorithm may look like this:

```
while true:
    header = new byte[5]
    offset = 0
    while offset < 5:
        size = read(header, offset, 5-offset)
        offset += size

    length = get_length_from_header(header)
    flag = get_flag_from_header(header)

    # The next lines buffer entire message into memory.
    # Be aware that this is not efficient for file upload,
    # which should be streamed directly into FS instead. 
    message = new bytes[length]
    offset = 0
    while offset < length:
        size = read(message, offset, length - offset)
        offset += size

    process_message(message, length, flag)
```

Here the `read` operation accepts an array, offset at which it should write to the array, and how many bytes it should read. It returns the real number of read bytes. So the standard low level read operation.

Of course this can be further optimized, e.g. reading 5 bytes only at the beginining is not necessarily efficient. We can read big buffer, say 4k bytes, and then analyze what we read. But it gets more complicated so lets leave it as it is.